# JPA: multiselect and LEFT JOINS

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I'm working on a complex query construction using JPA Criteria API, and I'm encountering a bit of an issue with my SQL result.

I have an Entity like this:

```
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ENTITY_ID", nullable = false)
    private Long pk;

    @Column(name = "DATE_FIELD")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private LocalDateTime dateField;

    @Column(name = "STRING_FIELD", nullable = false, length = 5)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private SourceQueue stringField;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ENTITY_ID", referencedColumnName = "PARENT_ID", nullable = false)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    private List<ChildEntity> childEntities;

    @Column(name = "CLOB_FIELD")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @Lob
    private String clobField;
```

I use a multiselect, because I want make it distinct and exclude the clobField. In order to construct a filter, I join the childEntity on a LEFT JOIN. But the criteria query constructs not only the LEFT JOIN, but also an old INNER JOIN (comma seperated table in FROM, link in WHERE), because the childEntity is (and has to be) part of the multiselect.

```
    @Override
    public Collection<MyEntity> findAllWithLimit(QueryParameters queryParameters) {
        final CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
        final CriteriaQuery<MyEntity> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(MyEntity.class);
        final Root<MyEntity> myEntityRoot = criteriaQuery.from(MyEntity.class);
        final Join<MyEntity, ChildEntity> childEntityJoin = myEntityRoot.join("childEntities", JoinType.LEFT);

        final List<Selection<?>> selections = getSelections(myEntityRoot);
        List<Predicate> predicateList = new ArrayList<>();

        predicateList.addAll(createChildEntityPredicates(criteriaBuilder, childEntityJoin, queryParameters));
        
        criteriaQuery.multiselect(selections);
        criteriaQuery.distinct(true);

        Predicate finalPredicate = criteriaBuilder.and(predicateList.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
        criteriaQuery.where(finalPredicate);

        Optional<Order> orderOptional = createOrderPredicate(criteriaBuilder,
            myEntityRoot, queryParameters.getSortField(), queryParameters.getSortOrder());
        orderOptional.ifPresent(criteriaQuery::orderBy);

        TypedQuery<MyEntity> query = getEntityManager().createQuery(criteriaQuery);
        query.setFirstResult(queryParameters.getFirstRowIndex());
        query.setMaxResults(queryParameters.getPageSize());
        query.setHint(QueryHints.MAINTAIN_CACHE, HintValues.FALSE);

        return query.getResultList();
    }

    private List<Selection<?>> getSelections(Root<MyEntity> root) {
        List<Selection<?>> selections = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> attributeNames = Stream.of("pk","dateField","stringField","childEntities").collect(Collectors.toList());
        attributeNames.forEach(attributeName -> selections.add(root.get(attributeName)));

        return selections;
    }
```

This creates an SQL like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.ENTITY_ID AS a1, 
                t1.DATE_FIELD AS a2, 
                t1.STRING_FIELD AS a3,  
                t0.TUINFOID AS a4, 
                t0.COMMENTS AS a5, 
FROM MY_ENTITY t1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN CHILD_ENTITY t2 
    ON (t2.PARENT_ID = t1.ENTITY_ID), 
CHILD_ENTITY t0 
WHERE ((t0.PARENT_ID = t1.ENTITY_ID) ORDER BY t1.ENTITY_ID;
```

How can I get the builder to leave the INNER JOIN out of the sql?

Original Problem is the CLOB and the distinct. I already tried to do this with a DTO. So far the multiselect yields the best outcome, because this is a very simplified Version of my code and DTO got really messy (and had the same problems in the long run).

Comment: The extra "LEFT OUTER JOIN CHILD_ENTITY t2 " is caused from you calling myEntityRoot.join("childEntities", JoinType.LEFT). This forces a join to be added to the query to be used for filtering - the SQL shows thought that you aren't really using it. The 'other' join, CHILD_ENTITY t0, is used for fetching; they must be separate so that filtering doesn't affect the view of the data in entities.

Comment: What exactly are you looking to build,- I don't see how you can get "select entity.pk, entity.dateField, entity.stringField, entity.childEntities from Entity entity" and work as you will get one row for every ChildEntity - so duplicate MyEntity instances, one per child. If you want to exclude certain fields from Entity instances, you might try using an EntityGraph as a fetchgraph to your query. This will cause anything not defined in the EntityGraph to be treated as lazy and so not be fetched without need of a multiselect. You could just mark the clob as lazy with @Basic(fetch=LAZY)

Comment: Sry, simplified to much. Problem is, I have 4 Childs. All of them are lazy loaded. Problem is, I do not get results, when one of them has no related dataset, because of the INNER JOIN, the multiselect builds. I will try the EntityGraph.

Comment: You'll still have a problem with the childEntities relationship, as JPA will be required to do a fetch join (left or not) and return each in the collection individually. The join itself is because you call root.get("childEntities"). You'll want to instead use the childEntityJoin you created earlier since it defined a left join.

Answer (score 0):

`LEFT JOIN` and `LEFT OUTER JOIN` are the same.

The database driver will generate the SQL query for you. As long as you have the correct driver for your database version you shouldn't be concerned about this.